# How to fix unity error CS0176 with scenemanager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene-manager

My Problem is the following:

I´m trying to code a script for Unity with which I can change the scene when one specific Object was clicked.
But I get the following error:

NewBehaviourScript.cs(19,21): error CS0176: Member 'SceneManager.LoadScene(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.name == "Cube")
                {
                    SceneManager mySceneManager = new SceneManager();
                    mySceneManager.LoadScene("SceneTwo");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SceneManager.LoadScene` is a static method. This means it belongs to a type `SceneManager`, not some instance of `SceneManager`. This means you don't have to create new instance of `SceneManager` and instead of

```
SceneManager mySceneManager = new SceneManager();
mySceneManager.LoadScene("SceneTwo");
```

just use

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("SceneTwo");
```

You can read more about static members in c# in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members). Also next time first look for examples in [Unity's documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html), it can save you some time.